# receiving bytes in different sizes from c++ server to python client

Tags: python, c++, image, sockets

I am trying to send a few images taken from a folder from C++ server to Python client.
I have managed to send/receive the sizes as integers, but now I have to send/receive the actual images.
Since the images have different sizes, I would like  the client to split the bytes according the images sizes.

I am a bit lost, since I am using one parameter now e.g. `recv(1024)`
and I am receiving a lot more bytes than the ones I sent. So I am not really sure of what's happening.

## Server

```c++
    ifstream stream(nm, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(stream.is_open())
    {


vector<char> imageDataVec((istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
cout << "Size=of=image=== " << imageDataVec.size() << " bytes";
long conv_num= htonl(imageDataVec.size());
//send(new_socket, &converted_number, sizeof(converted_number), 0);
//send(new_socket, &imageDataVec, imageDataVec.size() , 0);

//size_t sent{};
int nbytes=0;  

while (1) 
    {

    //send(new_socket, &conv_num, sizeof(conv_num), 0);
     nbytes = send(new_socket, &imageDataVec, imageDataVec.size(), 0);
//continue;
    if (nbytes <= 0) {
        std::clog << "error: while sending image\n";
        break;
}
    else
{
    //sent += nbytes;
    cout<<nbytes<<"=====1=1=1=1========"<<"bytes"<<endl;}
                       break;

    }
//fclose(fin);
}
else
{cout<<"can't open folder"<<endl;}
```

## Client

```python
 while(1):
    pic_bytes=s.recv(8)
    pic_bytes_amount=int.from_bytes(pic_bytes, byteorder='big', signed=False)
    print("received bytes======{}".format(pic_bytes_amount))
    f=open('pic.jpeg','wb')
    f.write(pic_bytes)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

1) it seems strange that you are writing address of a vector to socket.

i think send should look like this:

```
send(new_socket, imageDataVec.data()...);
```

2) as i understand, on client side you are trying to read 8 byte length integer. but i don't see where server writes this data.

3) use int64_t instead of long type as you cannot be sure about long size.